# nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to "" Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v18.1.0` to unset it

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-ec2, nvm

I am using ssh to connect Github with AWS EC2 and I am trying to install the node so I can run my server in VM. but it is showing me an error says

> "nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently. set to ""Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v18.1.0` to unset it."

Comment: I get the same error when following this AWS guide: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html

Specifically, this command `. ~/.nvm/nvm.sh` leads to this output:
node: /lib64/libm.so.6: version GLIBC_2.27 not found (required by node)
node: /lib64/libc.so.6: version GLIBC_2.28 not found (required by node)
nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `nvm use --delete-prefix v18.1.0 --silent` to unset it.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a solution, but I got around the issue by changing to an older version of Node (v15 rather than the default v18) that doesn't require the latest GLIBC.

Run `nvm install 15` and `nvm use 15`